# Looking for C# ODBC database access

Tags: c#, sqlite, odbc

I have been struggling a little bit with an issue in a relational database that supports queries. Originally
I was going to use an OleDB data adapter and connect to an Microsoft Access database (created with Access 2000). 
The problem is that when I use a connection string like:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdbfile.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourpassword;

I get an error message about MDAC 2.6 or greater needs to be installed.  I have even tried to use an alternate connection string:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdbfile.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourpassword

I still get this MDAC error when I try to open the database.

Then I started thinking about using alternate databases such as SQlite. SQLServer or Oracle type of databaseswhich require servers are probably overkill as there are only a small number of users of the database.

What is a good database to use that has good c# .NET support and is fast?

Comment: Could you please let me know how you solved your problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider an object database. I recommend db4o. Its very fast and easy to use. It also have support for Linq.

Answer (score 2):

There are dime a dozen light-weight databases out there.

A couple that I have used quite often:

1. [**Firebird**](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/)
2. [**SqlLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

A note about firebird is that it can go from running in-process (embedded) to a full fledged server installation.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is awesome for what you are looking for. I wrote a pretty hefty how-to [on my blog](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/using-sqlite-with-csharp/) a while back, but the gist of it is that you get the System.Data.SQLite package and use it, and it works beautifully. Enjoy!